# Barra de menú editable

Tags: wordpress

soy nueva en WordPress y tengo que realizar este menú [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] quisiera saber si es posible editarlo desde el admin de WordPress o directo en el código.

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Puedes hacerlo desde el admin de WP: `tu-sitio.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php` [Ver todo explicado aquí](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) o también directo en el código.